# How can I dual tag GA4 and UA using GA4 EE Events with GTM?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, enhanced-ecommerce

Hi I recently updated all of the Firebase events in my app using the new GA4 Enhanced ecommerce nomenclature. ("ecommerce_purchase" to "purchase", "view_item", "select_item", "view_promotion" and "select_promotion"). However, we still want to keep sending these events to Universal Analytics through Android and iOS GTMs. We updated the tag triggers to the new event names, but data doesn't seem to arrive in Universal Analytics. My Enhanced Configuration still the same.

[image]

I tried using the event modifier tag and the "Use GA4 Schema" option. Now I'm testing the variable option for EE